# batch file that closes one window when more of the same program are open

Tags: batch-file, command, adobe

I need a batch file that opens then prints and then closes an adobe file.

It can be that there are mutiple adobe windows open, so it needs to close specificly the one that the batch file has opened.

please help me

cheers!

Comment: if you use the `/t` option for adobe command line printing, acrobat or reader will terminate after printing.

Comment: This is what i have now, where do I add the /t correctly?

AcroRd32.exe /t "\\EINSTEIN\Archiefmfe\Actueel\4022\637\4022.637.46501_01_110_001.pdf" \\Hertz\MFE_A3

Comment: Example: `"adobepath\AdobeProg.exe" /h /s /t "file.pdf" "PrinterName" "PrinterDriver" "PrinterPort"`